# Is this question subjective? Or when is a question subjective?

Tags: discussion

It is very easy to convert a subjective question to a question which no longer will be perceived as subjective.

And at the same time, questions which one may not call subjective are sometimes perceived to be subjective.

> `Why did X happen?` to `Why do you think X happened?`

To me the first one was **not** subjective. Because it seems like a question about history. But such a question was closed once and was reopened in the new format.

Eventually appending another format of the question towards the end of the original question received warm welcome.

> `What technological factors led for X to happen?`

But what I see is, it's the same question all along.

How do you draw the line as an asker? When do you vote to close a question as subjective? What is subjective? Is this subjective?

**Edit:** Looking at rosinante's response I think I should point out that [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3979679/399268) dealt only with available history.

Comment: In a room of objectivists, does the subjective question still make a sound?

Comment: Your question about subjectivity is itself subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are — perhaps ironically — many answers to this question. But the definition of subjective as far as Stack Exchange is concerned is available [from this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you think a subjective question can fixed through an edit, then go ahead and edit it.  That's what Stack Overflow is about - making things better.

But to answer the question, a question is subjective when answers to the question cannot be shown to be accurate or not by applying them and running the code in question to show that it has the intended effect.